# SharePoint content targeting, is it possible to have multiple views per user?

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

Our SharePoint site has a couple of broad groups that use it. In essence they are managers and users. We have different tabs viewable to the different people.
We now have a requirement for Managers to be able to pretend for a while that they are users, and see what users would normally see.

We cannot think of a way of achieving this toggle, what we don't want is for managers to get ALL the tabs that managers and users see, but be able to switch views on demand.

It is not required that users are excluded from manager content if they can guess the url, but equally if they are excluded then that is not a big problem.

We can write code if required, we are just not sure where to start with this!

Edit: There are whole sub-sites and pages of info for both audiences, not simply content on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the manager content and the user content in separate divs. Create a content editor web part, and use javascript to hide the irrelevant div based on the query string. Then link to:

```
mypage.aspx?page=manager
```

This worked really well for a similar project I had.